# How to make timing differences between groups

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, dplyr

I have a problem related with timing differences and I am trying to solve via `dplyr`. My initial data frame looks like this :

```
Paper <- data.frame(
  Student = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
  Dates = c("2014-04-17", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18","2014-04-18"),
  Time = c("10:35:00", "11:25:00", "19:15:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "22:21:26", "10:25:00", "11:15:00", "16:05:00", "17:25:00"),
  Connection = c("Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final")
)
```

or

```
   Student      Dates     Time  Connection
       A    2014-04-17  10:35:00    Initial
       A    2014-04-17  11:25:00      Final
       A    2014-04-17  19:15:00    Initial
       A    2014-04-17  21:00:00      Final
       A    2014-04-18  22:00:00    Initial
       A    2014-04-18  22:21:26      Final
       B    2014-04-18  10:25:00    Initial
       B    2014-04-18  11:15:00      Final
       B    2014-04-18  16:05:00    Initial
       B    2014-04-18  17:25:00      Final
```

I am trying to to know for each `Date` the time dedicated by `Student` considering that the real time calculated is between the `"Initial"` and `"Final"` `Connection`.

So my expected data frame would look like this :

```
  Student    Dates    Time (Minutes)
     A    14-04-17     155
     A    14-04-18   21.43
     B    14-04-18     130
```

I have tried this, and I almost got the solution but I don't know how to consider the calculation of the difference of time between connection (`"Initial"`/`"Final"`) so I obtain this:

```
Paper$Dates <- as.Date(Paper$Dates, "%Y-%m-%d")

Paper$Time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(as.character(Paper$Time),
                         format = "%H:%M:%S"))

FinalPaper <- 
  Paper %>% 
  group_by(Student, Dates) %>% 
  summarise(TimeSpent = sum(diff(Time))) %>% 
  mutate(TimeSpent = TimeSpent/60) %>% 
  mutate(TimeSpent = round(TimeSpent, digits = 2))
```

Resulting

```
  Student      Dates   TimeSpent
1       A   2014-04-17    625.00
2       A   2014-04-18     21.43
3       B   2014-04-18    420.00
```

As can be seen in the `TimeSpent` the time is higher this is because I am not considering the connection so it is calculating wrong times. For example for the student A it is calculating the time between `10:35:00` and `21:00:00` which is wrong.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Good question, well explained problem and reproducible data and code. Thanks for that ;) One thing though; in your expected `data.frame`, the line     `A    14-04-18    60` is wrong wright?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an id to each 'session', with `cumsum(Connection == "Initial")`. Prerequisite for this is that the data is sorted in the way you have presented it here. We can then calculate the time difference for each session, and aggregate again to get the total time spent per student per date:

```
Paper <- data.frame(
  Student = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
  Dates= c("2014-04-17", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-18","2014-04-18"),
  Time = c("10:35:00", "11:25:00", "19:15:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "22:21:26", "10:25:00", "11:15:00", "16:05:00", "17:25:00"), 
  Connection = c("Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final", "Initial", "Final")
)

Paper$Dates <- as.Date(Paper$Dates, "%Y-%m-%d")
Paper$Time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(as.character(Paper$Time),
                                    format = "%H:%M:%S"))

FinalPaper <- Paper %>% 
  mutate(seqid = cumsum(Connection == "Initial")) %>% 
  group_by(Student, Dates, seqid) %>% 
  summarise(TimeSpent = sum(diff(Time))) %>% 
  group_by(Student, Dates) %>% 
  summarise(TimeSpent = round(sum(TimeSpent)/60,2))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Student [2]
  Student      Dates TimeSpent
   <fctr>     <date>     <dbl>
1       A 2014-04-17    155.00
2       A 2014-04-18     21.43
3       B 2014-04-18    130.00
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

And here is a `data.table` based solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Paper)
Paper[order(Student, Time), .(
    TimeSpend = sum(c(0,diff(Time))[Connection == "Final"])/60
  ), by = .(Student, Dates)]

   Student      Dates TimeSpend
1:       A 2014-04-17 155.00000
2:       A 2014-04-18  21.43333
3:       B 2014-04-18 130.00000
```